# How to build syntax trees for non-compilable code snippets?

Tags: compilation, abstract-syntax-tree, code-snippets

How to build syntax trees to represent code snippets if they cannot be compiled successfully?
Can I use PCFG to to represent the non-compilable code?

Comment: What do you mean by 'cannot be compiled successfully'? Do you mean the snippet contains syntax errors or (for example) undefined variables?

Comment: @Nick Yes. The snippet has syntax errors, so it cannot be compiled.

Comment: Can you give an example of an uncompilable snippet and what you would like the tree to look like?

Comment: @Nick Some snippets on stackoverflow are not finished with “...”, but I need to build the ast tree to extract their structural information.

Comment: @Nick e.g. int main() {printf("hello"); ...}

Comment: Oh, I see now what it is you mean. What happens if you define the ellipsis as whitespace, treat it as an inline comment like '/* */' or preprocess it to remove it? If it has been used properly, it shouldn't omit anything 'structural' that would impact the ST.

Comment: @Nick And what if some errors, e.g. losing semicolon?

Comment: Replace the ellipsis with a ';', you can't go wrong then! It will either 'replace' a missing one or stick in a null command that won't affect anything.

Comment: @Nick so I need to correct the snippets respectively before build the tree?

Comment: @Nick May I ask another question? Can I use PCFG to build the syntax tree for the snippet?

Comment: Yes, it will be much easier/better if you preprocess the input in the way we've discussed so that it doesn't appear there's an error.